# Should I use a website form or a diy form program as MySQL front-end?

Tags: mysql, frontend, software-design

I have a MySQL db that is supposed to store shift details like start time, employee, breaks, nr. of items processed etc. to then analyze this data with MS PowerBI.

The employees are supposed to enter the data themselves after their shift and be separated from the data (not see or change it afterwards).

How should I set up the form the employees enter their data into? Should I make a website with a form on it or should I make a diy program that connects to the db?

I am quite new to all of this so I’m trying to find the best way to complete this.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a best guess. Yes, create a website which allows the employee to enter the details, grab the info with a back end application (php/java/kotlin/nodejs/python ... e.t.c), and do not develop a page that retrieve data to the website for the employees.

Afterwards, you can export your data to your desired application (you might need to develop something for smooth data transfer as well)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "do not develop a page that retrieve data to the website for the employees.". Could elaboarte on that? On the data transfer: Can I just use the MySQL connectors to export the data to the db or should I use something else?

Comment: Another thing. Is phpmyadmin suited for something like this?

Comment: phpmyadmin is definitly suitable

Comment: When I say do not develop a page that retrieves data to the website for the employees, I mean "do not develop a functionality for them to be able to edit the info". Yes, you can use MySQL connectors to export the data to db. (but with php, you don't need a MySQL connector. it comes built in the language)